# How do I save text in a text area when I reload the page using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I am somewhat new to code and I am creating a calendar on http://codepen.io/. I have a textarea where I can jot down events for the month. I have the textarea saved to a variable when I click a button. But I want to save that textarea data so when I reload the page the data in the textarea is saved. I have come across some people using cookies to store the data but I am lost when it comes to using cookies. Is there anyway to save this data? So far my code looks like this:

```
<div class="dropdownevent" id="myDropdown">
<p><textarea id="myTextArea" rows="6"></textarea></p><button   
class="buttonsave btn btn-default" id="save">Save Events</button>
</div><!--End dropdownevent-->

$("#save").click(function() {
var saveText = $("textarea#myTextArea").val();

document.getElementById("myTextArea").innerHTML = saveText;

/*alert(saveText);*/
});
```

I want to use only jquery and javascript if it is possible. I want to save the data from my textarea on reload but have no clue on how to do that.

Comment: [Using the Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use localStorage.

You can use it like an object:

```
localStorage.value=yourValue;
```

And you will save on browser storage the value.

Simply then you can use it on page load, and get the value you stored inside it.

```
// Store
localStorage.lastname = "Smith";
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.lastname;
```

you can read more about localStorage [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)